# Is there a way to use an Oval object with the intersects() function?

Tags: java, geometry, collision, oval

First of all, I know that there are very similar questions answered already, but I haven't seen this question in particular asked yet.

I have an oval and a rectangle and I want to detect if they are intersecting. I know you can do this with two rectangles like so:

```
if (new Rectangle(x1, y1, w1, h1).intersects(new Rectangle(x2, y2, w2, h2))) {

    //code here for when collision occurs.

}
```

Is it possible to do this with an oval like so?

```
if (new Oval(x1, y1, w1, h1).intersects(new Rectangle(x2, y2, w2, h2))) {

    //code here for when collision occurs.

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see an Oval class when I search for one, so I will use Ellipse as an example.  If you look at the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) you will see the docs for the `Shape` class.

This class is extended by both `Rectangle` and `Ellipse` and also contains an `intersect(Shape, Shape)` method, so therefore you will be able to use intersect on both of these objects.

If your `Oval` class and `Rectangle` class both extend the same `Shape` Class in your scenario from where the `intersect(Shape, Shape)` is inherited from, it will work in your scenario as well.